# jQuery: Get HTML including the selector?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Say I have this HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li id="example"><strong>Awesome</strong> example text</li>
</ul>
```

I want to be able to do something like `$('#example').html()` but right now doing that obviously only gets `<strong>Awesome</strong> example text`.

So how can I get the HTML *including* the selected element?

ie. `<li id="example"><strong>Awesome</strong> example text</li>`

I'm using jQuery 1.4.4.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/jquery-get-selected-elements-outer-html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/jquery-get-selected-elements-outer-html is the best approach I have known yet.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In this specific case:

```
var outerHTML = $("<div />").append($('#example').clone()).html();
```

See [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150317044938/http://darlesson.com/jquery/outerhtml/) for more details.

And the discussion here: http://api.jquery.com/html/ (this explains that this isn't in jQuery core and why some logical solutions won't work)

Comment: why don't to use `wrap`? It is cleaner, I think

Comment: Because using wrap actually affects the DOM tree displayed to the user. This doesn't.

Comment: I'm being thrown by the $("<div />") selector. I am accustomed to seeing $('div'), but not with the brackets and such. Can you, or someone, explain to me what that is doing? Also, it is desirable not to add it to the DOM, but, again, I'm confused why it doesn't. I think if I understood the first part, I'd understand why. Can anyone explain?

Comment: @SteveC. "<div/>" isn't a selector here. `$("<div />")` constructs a new div element. See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Answer (score 6):

You could try this:

```
var html = $('<div>').append($('#example').clone()).html();
```

Comment: is the remove() necessary? Is some kind of memory leak produced otherwise?

Comment: Guess it's not necessary if it never gets added to the dom. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For browsers that support it, outerHTML can do that. There are jQuery plugins like [this](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2007/06/17/jquery-snippets-outerhtml/) and [this](http://yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/) that enable support via some clever jQuery.

Answer (score -2):

```
var outerHtml = $('#example').detach();
```

Comment: The .detach() method is the same as .remove() , except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements

Answer (score -4):

Anything wrong with simply using $('#example') ? This grabs the whole thing!

Comment: this grabs the jquery object of this element, not the html string