# Confused about adding multiple td's to tr using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            $("#txt").click(function () {
                var $TableRow = $('<tr></tr>');
                var $TableData = $('<td></td>');
                var $TableData2 = $('<td></td>');

                // Works
                $("#tblControls").append(
                $TableRow.html(
                $TableData.text("Test, Hello World3")
            )
    );

</script>
<div style="display: inline">
    <input type="button" id="txt" value="Add TextBox" style="" />
</div>
<br/>
<table id="tblControls" width="100%">

</table>
```

But why does this not add two td's to the tr?

```
$("#tblControls").append(
    $TableRow.html(
        $TableData.text("Test, Hello World3")
        +
        $TableData2.text("Test, Hello World4")
    )
);
```

What I get is this:

```
[object Object][object Object]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to combine two jQuery objects, not two HTML-strings. The `.text()` method return the jQuery object to support chaining, not the element's HTML as a string.

You can refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587844/jquery-get-html-including-the-selector) on how to get the HTML of the entire element, including the actual element.

This is untested, but something like this should do it:

```
$("#tblControls").append(
        $TableRow.html(
            $("<div />").append($TableData.text("Test, Hello World3")).html() + 
            $("<div />").append($TableData2.text("Test, Hello World4")).html() 
        ) 
);
```

However, the jQuery documentation says this about what .append() expect:

> DOM element, HTML string, or jQuery object to insert at the end of
>   each element in the set of matched elements.

Since it can take a jQuery object, you can simply pass `$TableData` and `$TableData2` to the append-method.

```
$("#tblControls").append(
     $TableRow.append($TableData).append($TableData2);
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Christofer, that makes sense.  I'm really new to JQuery.  So .text() returns an object?

Comment: @Jason Most jQuery methods return the jQuery object to make it possible to chain methods like this `$("#something").hide().text("Some text").show();` However `.text()` return a text string, but if you call it to set the text `.text("Some text")` it will return the jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `+` operator will result in `toString` being called on the arguments on either side of it, which yields `[object Object]` (since `$TableData.text("...")` and such returns the jQuery object; see [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text) for details).

What you want is:

```
$TableRow.append($TableData).append($TableData2);
```

See [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append) in the documentation.

Once the page has been loaded, you need to think much more in terms of *objects* like elements and such, and less in terms of *markup*. When you get in the habit of that, it's very powerful.